# How can I edit what the user sees of their input after it has been entered?

Tags: c++, c++11, stream, console

Accepting input like below,

```
char ch = getch();
while(ch != '\r') {
    if(ch == '\b') {
        // do **something** here to remove the previous character from the stream 
    } else {
        cout << ch;
    }
}
```

I understand the stream is for inserting and extracting data.

Does this mean that once some data is posted to the stream it becomes immutable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a buffer in the I/O library that is in between your process and the OS/Kernel level system calls that ultimately read from the terminal or disk or some other device.

Once your process gets the byte from the I/O library, you can store it in an array and then you can implement the behavior of '\b' on your array of bytes.

So each one of the bytes goes through a pipe line of buffers from the device to I/O library to the buffer in your process. You can implement undo type behavior on the last stage of the pipe line which is in your process, the previous stages of pipe line are now history and you can't change the history.

You can use ungetc for pushing a byte you have read, back to the buffer of I/O library which can be read again later, but that seems tangential to your question.